# need to create a dashboard to monitor the status of spring batch job

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I need to create a dashboard to monitor the status of the spring batch jobs those jobs get executed by shell script. so I thought of getting the batch status from spring batch tables using rest Api like that and display that data using some UI framework. can you help me how I can implement this approach.

Comment: If you can use opensource project, I would definitely go with Spring Cloud Dataflow which is a job/task orchestrator

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do and to get a very intuitive UI without any kind of UI coding is to use Grafana + Prometheus Stack. You need to inject the time series data only to grafana in your REST API when it gets called.

like

And Grafana can automatically visualize it in its dashboard.

Take a look at here https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin if your batch jobs are in spring boot and you want add a web console to manage those batch jobs.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/2.x/reference/reference.xhtml